# PC not responding after starting a game

Tags: windows-10, freeze, gaming

After starting a game like Heros of Newearth or Witcher 3 my Windows shows the working mouse cursor but nothing happens. I am also not longer able to start programs or shut down the computer. The system is not completely frozen, but any interaction is not working. Programs that are already running go into not responding or do not allow any further interactions.

There is a process of the game running, but the memory usage is < 100 MB and no CPU usage is shown in the task manager.

I already installed the latest graphics driver for my GTX 960, because i assumed that it is a graphics card problem, but that did not fix the issue.

I would be happy if someone could give me hints to test what is the problem. Apparently the freeze only occurs when starting a game. Rendering or other media applications work fine. I tested the whole system with the Furmark benchmark for CPU and GPU. The temps seem to be okay with max 62°C for the CPU and 72°C for the GPU.

Edit: The first run of Furmark Crashed.

Comment: Have you ever waited and see how long it last? (Anecdotal) I was using a HDD before and if I run any big game (that requires to load lots of resources from the HDD) - the game will hang (and Windows may even think it crashed) - but it is simply the game loading all the needed resources from the slow HDD. That issue is gone after I replace my HDD into SSD. (note: only anecdotal and may be completely different to what you are experiencing)

Comment: The weird thing is that it worked 2 weeks ago. I also had the problem that i stated a few times, but now it seems to be permanent. Based on that i would argue that it is not a problem with the game loading data from a slow drive (its also on a SSD).

Comment: Another possibility is your game data may be corrupted (from whatever the reasons are) - if your game have a verify and fix option - try that first. If not - try re-installing and see if that helps?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your PC? Not shutting down, an actual reboot. Hold the power button for 4 seconds if you have to to force it to shutdown.

Comment: Rebooting is not working. I tried that multiple times.

Comment: What I think happened is that the system is paging some memory and it wasn't able to restore the paged memory back to RAM.